# Getting null value from @configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I'm creating pojo class and store the application.properties variable but I'm getting null values

NOTE: need to access env from my Abstract class

POJO class

```java
package mynt.xyz.c4.pushnotif.config;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration("notificationEnvironment")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.notif")
public class NotificationEnvironment {
    private String key;
    private String url;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

Initializing class with @autowired

```java
public abstract class NotificationBase {

    @Autowired
    NotificationEnvironment notificationEnvironment;

    public void getEnv(){
    system.out.println(notificationEnvironment.getKey()); // null value
    }
}
```

concrete class that extend to my NotificationBaseClass

```java
@Component
@Qualifier("androidNotification")
public class AndroidNotification extends NotificationBase implements Notification {

    public AndroidNotification(String message, String title, String datalink, List<String> instanceIds) {
        super(message, title, datalink, instanceIds);
    }

    AndroidNotification(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void send() {
        this.getEnv();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```java
app.notif.key=jkashdkjashd
app.notif.url=https/some.url
```

Comment: works fine for me, can you add, how are you testing it.

Comment: If you are accessing from `NotificationBase` class, since it is abstract class, it will not add @autowired dependencies, make it none abstract and check, and add `@Component`, this should work fine.

Comment: @dkb dont know why it's not working for me i'm stuck on this problem.
using postman to test my api I got an error with java null pointer exception.

Comment: @dkb I extend my NotificationBase class to my two concrete class that they 
are sharing same attributes I need this to be abstract and call getEnv method.
do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: if possible can you please add, one of the concrete class definition in question.

Comment: Autowiring will only work in spring beans. if the classes extending from `NotificationBase` aren't spring beans but managed by yourself by doing `new MyExtendedNotificationBase` autowiriung will not work.

Comment: already added @dkb 
I eddited my code sorry for non sense void method

Comment: M.Deinum my concrete classes has @Component annotation is that not counted as bean?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57752654/2987755, should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can [auto wire @Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s02.html) class from **`@Configuration`** class

> @Configuration class may reference the instance of any other @Configuration class using @Autowired. This works because the @Configuration classes themselves are instantiated and managed as individual Spring beans.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class @Component and add prefix value in @ConfigurationProperties, like this. This works for me, hope this works for you as well.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.notif")
public class NotificationEnvironment {
    private String key;
    private String url;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

}
```

You can use this properties like this:

```
@Component
public class NotificationBase {

    private static NotificationEnvironment notificationEnvironment;

    @Autowired
    public NotificationBase(NotificationEnvironment notificationEnvironment){
        this.notificationEnvironment = notificationEnvironment;
    }

    public static void getEnv(){
        System.out.println(notificationEnvironment.getKey()); // null value
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one of the concrete class definition as OP author mentioned.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ConcreteNotification extends NotificationBase {

    @Autowired
    public ConcreteNotification(NotificationEnvironment notificationEnvironment) {
        super(notificationEnvironment);
    }
}
```

updated NotificationBase as below

```java
public abstract class NotificationBase {

    NotificationEnvironment notificationEnvironment;

    public NotificationBase(NotificationEnvironment notificationEnvironment) {
        this.notificationEnvironment = notificationEnvironment;
    }

    public void getEnv(){
        System.out.println(notificationEnvironment.getKey());
    }
}
```

The controller class I am using to get configuration values

```java
@RestController
public class ArticleCommentController {

    @Autowired
    ConcreteNotification concreteNotification;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/health_check", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getDemo() {
        concreteNotification.getEnv();
    }
}
```

output:

jkashdkjashd

Comment: I've still not getting my environment

Comment: Then there can be some other issue related to spring config, for reference: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa, used same way it is in github repo.

Comment: if possible can you share code in github, will check

Comment: I've get my property with @Autowire
in CommandLineRunner run method
but not working in my concrete classes

Comment: I am adding it to application.properties file and able to get it from there. may be for start, add it in application.properties then go for command line argument with -D flag

Comment: I have factory class that return my concrete classes, I able to get my environment in my factory class with @Autowire too.
I think because of this initialization: return new AndroidNotification(message, title, datalink, instanceIds); 
I think this is the cause why I cannot get my environment

Comment: you need to add `public NotificationBase(NotificationEnvironment notificationEnvironment) {
        this.notificationEnvironment = notificationEnvironment;
    }` in NotificationBase.java

Comment: also `@Autowired
    public ConcreteNotification(NotificationEnvironment notificationEnvironment) {
        super(notificationEnvironment);
    }` in ConcreteNotification.java